# php forms: value="<?php=$_POST['total_amount']?> vs. value="<?=$_POST['total_amount']?>

Tags: php, forms, variables, post

My form is generating an error when I use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="total_amount" value="<?php=$_POST['total_amount']?>" />
```

however it works fine when I use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="total_amount" value="<?=$_POST['total_amount']?>" />
```

I thought it was insecure to use `<?=` instead of `<?php`.

Here is the complete form:

```
<form name="save_file" action="cyprus_funds_transfer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <? if($_POST['value_type'] == 1) {?>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php=$_POST['account_number']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="value_type" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="total_amount" value="<?php=$_POST['total_amount']?>" />
  <? } else { ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php=$_POST['amount']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="value_type" value="0" />
  <? } ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="to" value="<?php=$_POST['send_to']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="from" value="<?php=$_POST['send_from']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="message" value="<?php=$_POST['message']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="save" />
  <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php=$order_id?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="email_id" value="<?php=$_POST['email_id']?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Still, this all is bad practice. Try to split the PHP and HTML.

Comment: And use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting user data to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: It is not "insecure" to use short tags... they are just not always enabled on all server configurations so your code may not work if hosted on a different server. In the first example, you would just need to change the <?php=... ?> to <?php echo ... ?>

Comment: Agree with @mjayt. Also, PHP Short Tags are enabled by default in PHP 5.4+

Comment: You guys rock.  The code/script was programmed by Indian developers on Elance.com

Comment: @Bond and Marcel ~ any good examples of split php and html forms.  Kinda new to web programming and examples would be great.  An example using htmlspecialchars would be great too.  Although htmlspecialcars is not recommended for database input, right?

The code/script was programmed by Indian developers on Elance.com As I suspected, in other parts of the code, they coded vulnerabilities into the scripts at certain points.  For instance, they like to use $_request in certain places, which makes sense, since one of the xss exploits is a cookie grab.

Comment: Personally I love [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Smarty-Template-Engine-Tutorial-P849.html)

Comment: this is xxs vulnerabil. If you post in the email `alert('hello')` you will see what I mean. Never use `$_POST` data in the input value

Comment: You have certain misconceptions about preventing XSS and SQL injections. The short answer is: escape on output, not input. When doing database transactions, use parameterized queries using PDO or MySQLi (or use `mysql_real_escape_string` when you insist on using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions). When passing query parameters in a URL, use `rawurlencode`. It all depends on the context where you are using user input. See more in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2119083/258127). And if I were you, I would ask (part of) my money back, as they created insecure code for you.

Comment: @marcelKorpel... Any recommended reading?  thanks to the input that I've been receiving on the internet in forums like this, I didn't have to pay one dime.  I do still have the code, and I'm taking a course in php, et al. and am trying to re-code it on my own, removing the vulnerabilities as I go.

As for the misconceptions, the more I learn, the less of those I'll have.

Comment: @s.visser Thanks for the tip.  Can you recommended any readings or links for me to study?

Comment: @codeipusrex a fine article is http://phpmaster.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/ . But stick to the `never trust a user` rule, always check in and out puts.

Comment: Do any of you do any freelance work?  Would love to hire someone to audit the code and fix any vulnerabilities.  There are 4 primary files, a few functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong way

```
<?php=$_POST['send_to']?>
```

this is correct way

```
<?=$_POST['send_to']?> is similar to <?php echo $_POST['send_to']; ?>
```

## Codepad

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<?php=$_POST['send_to'];?>
```

to this

```
<?=$_POST['send_to'];?>
```

or with this

```
<?php echo $_POST['send_to'];?>
```